# Variable/class in array

Tags: arrays, swift

So i'm kinda stuck on somethng.
i kinda want a random drop wen i kill my monster.
this is what i got.

i've got a weapon1

```
class weapon {
   var str = Int
}
class Weapon1: weapon {
    override init() {
        super.init()
 str = 10
}
class Weapon2: weapon {
    override init() {
        super.init()
 str = 20
}
```

i've got a monster

```
class monster {
   str = 20
   def = 10
   drops = [weapon1(), Weapon2()]
}
```

and i have a place to link my drops to if my monster is death

```
var itemdrops = weapon()
```

and when my monster dies it should link my monster drop to my itemdrops..
so i can use it somewhere like in an inventory.
but when i try to do it like this

```
random = (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(monster.items.count-1))) 

//-1 becous it would say 2 items and an array starts at 0
itemdrops = monster.items[random]
```

but then items is in white..

Comment: `class Weapon2` does not inherit from `weapon` — Also please use capital letter to start class names. — Also please show your real code. Copy and paste. Don't type it in by hand, making all kind of mistakes like this. We need to see real code in order to help you.

Comment: If i gone post al my code its gone be kind of messy...  The code is good, the thing that i want is to give my var itemdrops all the propertys of the dropped item..

Comment: The code isn't *good*, since it doesn't even compile. Not that it's hard to figure out why but I think it's common courtesy if you're asking for help ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `items` is an *instance* property of `monster`:

```
class monster {
   str = 20
   def = 10
   drops = [weapon1(), Weapon2()]
}
```

But when you try to access it, you try to access it through the *class*:

```
monster.items[random]
```

The class `monster` has no class/static property `items`, so your code cannot compile.

This is a good reason for using capital letters for class names, as you are supposed to. It helps you keep track of whether this thing is a class or an instance. Example:

```
class Monster {
   str = 20
   def = 10
   drops = [Weapon1(), Weapon2()] // assume you've named these classes correctly
}
```

Now, in your code, you would say:

```
let aMonster = Monster() // an _instance_
var itemdrops = aMonster.items[random]
```

Comment: Thanks that kinda helped me as i was hoping :) , 1 small issue now..,  my weapona hold an image. Img = UIImage(named: "sword") or something like that.  But i cant seem to ise it in itemdrops.img...

Comment: oke sorry bout that, will do :)
and thanks again for the Answering my question :)